# jQuery on FF3.6 - is there a limit on the data size for rendered content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

I'm running into strange data size limitation when returning data from the server with `jQuery.post`. My code looks something like this:

```
$.post('/search', query, function(data) {
  // data = { success : <true/false>, html : <html string> }
  if (data.success) {
    $('#search-results').html(data.html);
  } else {
    displayPrettyError('error!'); // :)
  }
}, 'json');
```

For large `data.html` (length > 3e6 chars), nothing seems to happen (nothing rendered) in Firefox 3.6, even though it works fine in later versions and on chrome. My entire organization is running FF3.6 - any idea if there's a way to resolve this oddity, or is it a known issue and I should just enforce a company wide browser upgrade? thanks.

**EDIT** - the returned response contains the already rendered html of a pretty big result set from a db query.

Comment: Try lessen the request lenght, it should never be large anyway, that's one of the main points about using Ajax. There are numerous ways to accomplish this.

Comment: I've never heard of this before (but similarly, never tried to send 3e6 chars via AJAX), however instead of forcing a company wide upgrade, why not split the response into multiple requests?

Comment: I could do that, but since it seems like a browser issue I'd rather see if a simpler solution (== no code modification) exists :)

Comment: Do you have firebug? Maybe disabling it could help. Have you tried it?

Comment: Is the last bracket being read as %7D or %Pr by FF? This question seems similar... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903088/problem-ajaxing-json-object-on-mac-firefox-version-3-6-12

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a version-specific issue of Firefox; might be [this bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=546028).

You're almost 3 full iterations behind the latest version of FF; also note, they plan to release a new iteration every 16 weeks or something ridiculous like that; see: [Firefox Roadmap](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Firefox/Roadmap#tl.3Bdr)

While I'm not saying you should be running the Aurora builds or anything, the current stable release is FF5, which will be FF6 in just under a week (Aug. 16 is when FF6 moves from Beta channel to stable; FF7 will then move from Aurora to Beta, and FF8 will move from Nightly to Aurora. See: [Release Tracking](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Features/Release_Tracking)). My point is that it's probably time to upgrade your company to a newer version *anyway*, if only for security reasons.

Just my two.

Comment: Actually, I'm running the latest build available (using firefox ppa) - in which it works fine - but as always, the company's IT department is not following suit :)

Comment: Yeah; that it works with newer versions but not older very much seems like a version-specific bug to me...